# Six balls numbered from 1 to 6. Which is the probability that the 2nd is greater than 1st?

Tags: probability

> One bag contains 6 balls numbered from one to six. They draw 2 without
>   replacement. Calculate the probability that the second extracted ball
>   has a greater number than the first one. Calculate the same
>   probabilities in case of extraction with replacement.

Well, maybe is a stupid question, but i’m not sure if i’m thinking in the correct way and i’m a beginner.

I’ve supposed that the cases where the second extraction is greater than the first is like sum the probabilities of order this balls in all positive cases.

So, if I draw a 1 at first extraction, I have 5 different possibilities to extract a ball that is greater than the first. With a draw of 2, I have 4 
..and so on..

But how can I calculate it? What’s the result?

---

**EDIT**:
Maybe I got the point. The result is:

1/6 ( 5/5 + 4/5 + 3/5 + 2/5 + 1/5 ) = 1/2

Can anyone confirm this, please?

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this?

Comment: @Bram28 sorry, i’ve changed the description of the question. Thank you for your interest and sorry for My bad english.

Comment: You're on the right way! Just keep going ... so you get 5+4+ .... =.. ways for the second one to be higher than the first. Divide this by the total number of ways you can pick two balls, and you will have your probability. Finally, once you have found that probability, think about why the probability is what it is :)

Comment: I was thinking the result was: 15/36, but i’m not sure of the sample space number. 6*6 is not the all possibile combination, because we can order it in 6! modes. 15 / (6!) can be correct?

Comment: Once you draw one ball, *without replacement*, there are *five* left in the bag from which to draw the second.  So the denominator should be $6\cdot 5$.

Comment: What is the probability that the second ball is less than the first.  Should it equal the probability that the second ball is greater than the first?  What is the chance that the second ball equals the first?  How does that change between the with replacement and without replacement scenarios.

Comment: GrahamKemp so 6! is correct, well. 
@DougM yes, it’s obvious the same (the inverse). The second ball equale the first must be 0 without replacement and 1/6 with replacement.

Answer (score 2):

> So, if I draw a 1 at first extraction, I have 5 different possibilities to extract a ball that is greater than the first. With a draw of 2, I have 4 ..and so on..

So that's $\tfrac 16\tfrac 55+\tfrac 16\tfrac 45+\cdots+\tfrac 16\tfrac 05=$ an unsurprising result.

---

What is the probability that the process results in the second ball showing a *lesser* number than the first?

Comment: To solve the second half of the problem: _with replacement_, there is a chance that the second ball has the _same_ number as the first. Now what is the relationship between the probabilities of these three events: 1. second > first, 2. second < first, 3. second = first?

Comment: The same i’m of the inverse. But I don’t get the point to how calculate it.

Comment: @obscurans so what is the correct answere to the first part?

Comment: *Without* replacement, it is impossible for the second ball to be the same as the first. There are two interesting events that are possible: 1. second > first, and 2. second < first. What is the relationship between their probabilities?

Comment: @devzu Look at the symmetry of the situation.

Comment: @GrahamKemp In this case the probability is: 1/6 5/6 + 1/6 4/6 + .... + 1/6 0/6.

Comment: Ok, maybe I know the result, i’m gong to edit the post description.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, we assume that every ball is equally likely to be drawn from the bag first; and then that every ball remaining in the bag is equally likely to be drawn second. You have already made these assumptions, and this is standard for problems of this kind.

So (without replacement) you have a set of outcomes, each of which has a first number and a second number different from the first. Each outcome is equally likely according to the assumptions.

Partition these outcomes into two subsets: subset $A$ in which the first number is greater than the second, and subset $B$ in which the second number is greater. Is it possible to map the members of $A$ to members of $B$ by swapping the first and second numbers? Is it a one-to-one mapping? What does that tell us about the relative sizes of the subsets and the relative probability of the events?

With replacement, you again have several outcomes, each a pair of numbers, each equally likely, but this time we partition the outcomes into three subsets: $A$ and $B$ as before, and a third subset $C$ containing outcomes in which the same number occurred twice. The same mapping between $A$ and $B$ applies, but their probabilities no longer add up to $1.$ Find the probability of $C,$ subtract that from $1,$ and now you can find the probabilities of each of the other two events.